# Trying to find a timer in Python

Tags: python, windows, memory, timer, windows-vista

I'm working on a Python program that is to use a timer.  It is going to be a memory game where a word pops up and a timer counts to 5 and after 5 seconds the words disappears and you have to type the word from memory.  I have already searched around a little and have seen things that time the execution time of a program but don't do anything that I want it to. Does anyone have a code to do such a thing? I'm using Python 2.7.3 on a Windows Vista computer.

Thanks in advance, Sid

Answer (score 2):

time.sleep(seconds) will sleep for some seconds and you can print a message

eg:

```
import time
for i in range(5,0,-1):
     print "%d Mins Left"%i
     time.sleep(60)
```

however if you want to update the previous time print you will need to look at the curses library (if you are using the terminal) or something like wxPython or pygame or any of the myriad of other graphical libraries for python if you want to use graphics

Answer (score 2):

Use the [time](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) module:

```
from time import time
start = int(time())
topass = 5
while int(time()) - topass < start:
    pass
print topass, "seconds have passed"
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is going to have a GUI, you could build this application easily using `Tkinter` using the `after` method of tkinter widgets.

If you're not going to have a GUI, you'll probably need 2 threads (1 to do the timing, 1 to accept input from the keyboard).

Comment: These are some great answers guys. Thanks. But how am I to make a certain word or character disappear?